# In a rigorous setting, how do I do this derivative using Ricci Calculus?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, index-notation

Let $R = \sqrt{x_k x_k}$. I want to calculate ${\partial R \over \partial x_i}$ and ${\partial^2 R \over \partial x_i \partial x_j}$. The solution was given as such:
$$ {\partial R \over \partial x_j} = {\partial (x_i x_i)^{1/2} \over \partial x_j} = {1 \over 2R} (\delta_{ij} x_i + x_i \delta_{ij} ) = {x_i \over R}$$
In this problem, the derivative of the outer function (per chain rule) was simply given as $1 \over 2R$. However, I want to maintain the notation for $R$ in terms of $x$. What is the rule for changing the dummy variable when taking the derivative? The function can be neither:
$$ {1 \over 2(x_i x_i)^{1/2}} (\delta_{ij} x_i + x_i \delta_{ij} )$$
nor:
$$ {1 \over 2(x_j x_j)^{1/2}} (\delta_{ij} x_i + x_i \delta_{ij} )$$
Because both would violate the rule of the dummy variable being repeated more than twice. Do I just randomly choose some new variable to put in the expression for the denominator, i.e.
$$ {1 \over 2(x_k x_k)^{1/2}} (\delta_{ij} x_i + x_i \delta_{ij} )$$
The same issue arises without loss of generality for taking the second derivative:
$$ {\partial^2 R \over \partial x_i \partial x_j} = {\delta_{ij} \over R} + x_i {\partial \over \partial x_j} {1 \over R} = {\delta_{ij} \over R} - {x_i x_j \over R^3}$$

Comment: You can avoid the confusion, if you denote $x\cdot x = x_kx_k$.
\begin{align*}
\partial_j(x\cdot x) &= \partial_j(x_kx_k)\\
&= 2x_k\partial_jx_k\\
&= 2x_k\delta_{jk}\\
&= 2x_j\\
R &= (x\cdot x)^{1/2}\\
\partial_jR &= \frac{1}{2}(x\cdot x)^{-1/2}\partial_j(x\cdot x)\\
&= (x\cdot x)^{-1/2}x_j\\
\partial_i(\partial_jR) &= \partial_i((x\cdot x)^{-1/2}x_j)\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}(x\cdot x)^{-3/2}x_j \partial_i(x\cdot x)
+ (x\cdot x)^{-1/2}\partial_ix_j\\
&= -(x\cdot x)^{-3/2}x_jx_i + (x\cdot x)^{-1/2}\delta_{ij}\\
&= \frac{\delta_{ij}}{R} - \frac{x_ix_j}{R^3}.
\end{align*}